# How to get object method (object."something"), where method name comes from a list of strings ("something" is a string)?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have a user form that contains lables. (I have to manually create each lable, since I can only place it in the correct spot by looking at the underlying image.) Each lable must go through the same "initializing" function that sets/re-sets its appearances. This leads to having the following:

```
 dummy = Initialize(UserForm1.Lable1)

 dummy = Initialize(UserForm1.Lable2)

 dummy = Initialize(UserForm1.Lable3)

 .

 .

 .
```

The names in my code are more descriptive, and I have the actual names for the lables stored in an excel sheet column. So, I would like to make a for loop that goes through that column, and substitutes ".Lable#" for ".(name from column)", like this:

```
 For i = 1 to 10

   dummy.Initialize(UserForm1.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2))

 Next i
```

The above code naturally doesn't work because the value from the cell is a string. Therefore, I need a way of converting that string to an object mothod name. Any ideas?

Hope this makes some sense, and that this is possible.

Thanks for your time,

Marvin

(I've learned all I know about VBA from the internet, so probably have some bad looking code. Suggestions for improvement are welcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For form controls, use the `Controls` method. This can be used on its own, or inside a loop:

```
for i=1 to 5
    frmUserForm.Controls("Label" & i).Enabled = True
next i
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you, that helped! I changed the line in my for-loop to somthing like this: dummy = Initialize(UserForm.Controls(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2))).